# Set the height of a fixed div (responsive)

Tags: css, responsive-design, positioning

I have got a site with a simple navigation at the bottom. That navigation has a fixed height of 100px at the left:

```
.mainNavigationWrapper{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
}
```

now, i want to fade-in a box when a specific button is clicked. That box should reach from the top of the document to the beginning of the nav. How do i achieve this, as i have a fixed height of the navigation, but a dynamic height of the box?

My personal workaround is the following script:

```
(function() {

var height = $(window).height() ;

console.log(height) ;
height = height - 100 ;

$('.treeMenu').css({
    'height': height
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $(window).height() ;

    console.log(height) ;
    height = height - 100 ;

    $('.treeMenu').css({
        'height': height
    });
});

}());
```

But that seems just wrong to me, i would like to know if there is any better way to do this, maybe with pure CSS.

Here is a fiddle to show the problem, solved with the solution mentioned above:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYNN7/)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/PpDQh/

```
.treeMenu{
overflow-y: auto;
position: fixed;
top: -100px;
background: rgba(18, 24, 18, 0.86);
width: 15em;
height: 100%;
}
.padder {
padding-top: 100px;
}
```

I set the height of treeMenu to 100% and added a padder-div inside.

Basically you let the additional 100px overlap at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another solution?

I used this, but in case there is a content-overflow, it causes the scrollbar to move upwards.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:

http://sprottenwels.net/drive/sc.png