# How to get correct overflow for proper div with fixed footer?

Tags: css

I am creating a site that has three major components - the navigation bar on the left, the central content (which is broken into a Title + Data), and a footer. The footer is fixed to the bottom of the page. I have JSFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6Ur89/1/

The issue I am running into is that, I want to the #data div to scroll vertically when it is too big for the div. The problem that I am seeing is that, when this happens, the div just gets pushed underneath the footer (instead of stopping at the footer) until infinity and scrolling never happens.

Within my CSS, I do have this:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

which I put in to prevent horizontal and vertical scroll bars appearing (presumably due to the footer). However, when I remove this style, the entire content div scrolls which is almost what I want (I would prefer that the title doesn't scroll...but that isn't the end of the world).

Can anybody provide any suggestions where I am going wrong? Again - want #data div to scroll and to stop at the footer. I want a fixed footer at the bottom of the site and I don't want the footer to create the scroll bars. Please let me know if you need clarifications.

**Update**: Yay for Stackoverflow - after typing up this question, one answer popped up immediately. I put a clearfix on the wrapper, so scrollbars don't appear due to the fixed footer. Updated my jsfiddle to reflect. So, essentially, I'm looking to understand how to *just* have the #data div scroll.

Comment: I think you just need to add a set height to the #data div

Comment: @DavidStetler - Do you mean a pixel height? What if I don't know that (since monitors with higher resolution in the y direction will have more pixels). Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: You could set the height with JavaScript, based on the windows size minus your header and footer.  There may be a better css only solution, but I am unaware of it.

Comment: so you dont want to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/399Ek/ and let the browser scroll bar be used to scroll?

Comment: also, I did a little research to try and find a solution to scroll y without a set height, and its pretty much not possible.  If you want to make it so just that data div scrolls you will need to use javascript to get the height and set it.

Comment: @DavidStetler - The fix you provided in your JSFiddle is essentially what my JSFiddle fix was in my post update. I just found it weird that the bar scrolled all the way into the footer rather than just being alongside the div. Not really a big deal...just bothered me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsu3Q/

added a padder inside the content div:

```
 <div id="content">
    <div class='padder'>
    <div id="title">title</div>
    <div id="data">Lots of data...

.padder {padding-top: 100px;}
```

moved the content 100px up outside the frame:

```
#content {
position: relative;
top: -100px;
margin-left: 350px;
height: 100%;}
```

This way you can use the height:100% property to match the height of the body 
AND subtract the 100px for your footer.

for a cleaner example look at a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15924302/1244950)